# Is it possible to save "points" as part of JPEG files metadata?

Tags: php, image-processing, photoshop

If so, how can it be acomplished? 
I'm using the PHP metadata toolkit and I thuoght that there's maybe a way of using some kind of "custom" index in the metadata of a JPEG image where I can save "points" information as a serialized array or so.

Am I too wrong?

Another question would be if there is a program which does this through a visual interface, because I've seen jpeg files created with photoshop which store their guide lines. In this case I don't need lines, I need "points".
Thank you.

Comment: What are these 'points'? Do you want to get the data of specific pixels to put in the metadata? Or do you want to capture one or more of the coordinates of the picture to save in the metadata so a script that can parse it can show a popup above the point?

Comment: Anyhow, Yes, there are programs that are able to edit the metadata of picture files. Quick google search came up with: [PhotoME](http://www.photome.de/). But if you want to edit the data using PHP, you would be better off using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or something similar.

Comment: @Qqwy The second one, I need to store something like [[12,23], [356,215], [765,123], ... etc] and access that information later via PHP to, as you say, show popups above those coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

After searching around on the internet for a bit, I found out about [PEL](http://lsolesen.github.com/pel/). This is a library wich can read, change, add and remove tags from the EXIF data of a JPG file. Using the `addEntry($e)` command you can add new tags to the EXIF data, for instance two new fields one for an X and an Y coordinate of your picture. Saving a two-number array serialized as a string could probably work too(wich would come in handy when you would want to store a long list of XY coordinates). You can read these tags out of the file again with the PHP Metadata Toolkit, but you can use PEL for that as well.